# Creation of Microsoft Azure Web App with sql server failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure-web-app-service

I got the following error when creating an azure web app:

Creation of Microsoft Azure Web App with sql server failed

I know what the issue is, but i dont know how to go back, change the settings and retry to create the web app. Can anyone advise how i do this?

Comment: Can you please add some more information? How did you try and create the web app? What is the issue / setting you are trying to change?

Comment: Have you tried deleting everything and starting from scratch?

Comment: I can start from scratch, and that indeed fixes the issue ( incorrect database settings was the issue) however i want to know how i can fix this without having to start from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment, did you try editing the publish profile and correct the settings that where incorrect?

You can edit the publish profile found under "Properties". It is an XML file that contains all the settings for publishing your site.

More information can be found here: [How to: Edit Deployment Settings in Publish Profile (.pubxml) Files and the .wpp.targets File in Visual Studio Web Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398069(v=vs.110).aspx)

[image]